# No crash-reports in Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, crash, google-play, crash-reports

Anyone else experiencing that crash-reports and ANRS no longer show up in the Developer Console?

We've just release a big update to our software to about 200 000 devices. And we know that it's crashing during startup for a small set of users. But still we receive nothing in the console.

It's been about 30 hours since the app went live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only receive a report if a user reports it after the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit older question but here is my 2 cents.

So, it depends on the users decision to 'Send Report' or not.

You can move to a third-party crash reporter (see suggestions @ [Crashes in Google Play Developer console vs Crashlytics Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293947/crashes-in-google-play-developer-console-vs-crashlytics-console)) or try tasting Firebase Crash Reporting (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash).