# Crashes in Google Play Developer console vs Crashlytics Console

Tags: android, google-play, crashlytics, developer-console

We have an Android App on Google play store . The Crashes & ANR section of the app lists only a handful of top crashes where as our Crashlytics console lists a total different set of crashes - I mean that only few of the top crashes in Crashlytics are same as one in Playstore.
One of the reasons can be that our App is also distributed via an Enterprise store private to our customer's setup.

```
1. Do these crashes also get shown up in Google Play Dev Console ?
2. Also if I can get all the crashes in Play Dev Console as I see in Crashlytics. ?
```

Answer (score 7):

I have used Google Play, Crittercism, Crashlytics and HockeyApp to track crashes in Android SDK and NDK derived applications.

My answers to your questions...

1) You will never be able to get all of the crashes in Google Play Dev Console. Google Play simply does not do a good job tracking crashes. In many versions, it requests that the user 'Send Report' and many people just click cancel. Google Play also only collects crashes from certain recognized devices and regions.

2) The weaknesses of Google Play's crash reporting system will push you to use a third-party crash reporter. At this point I would never release an application that depended strictly on Google Play for crash reporting -- you will simply miss the vast majority of user issues if you do this.

Our process is to ignore Google Play Dev Console's crash reports, but use their ANR reports (which are harder to get in other crash reporters.)

Comment: thanks @CoryTrese.  We have the same policy but I was just trying to see if  I can get more information from Google play crashes. Yes ANR are valuable and play goes a good job there

Comment: After several months of working with the Google Play team on this issue, it is my belief that the Dev Console simply does not work for collecting crashes. According to Crittercism, it only tracks around 5% of ANR that occur on deployed devices. If you find a better answer, I would love to hear about it but as far as my research has shown, what I posted is the basic (but unfortunate) truth.

Comment: @CoryTrese Of the three 3rd party crash reporters, which would you recommend?

Comment: HockeyApp is my recommendation.

Comment: Do you think Google Play Dev Console's crash reports still useless?

Comment: i'm using fabric as a third party crash reporter and analyzer. It's fine but the crash data (Count-type-..) shown in fabric differs from play console!

Answer (score 1):

As said, it depends on the users decision to 'Send Report' or not. You can move to a third-party crash reporter or try tasting Firebase Crash Reporting (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash).