# What to do when app keeps crashing and reports IllegalStateException with unknown source?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, illegalstateexception

Recently I updated my app by adding a couple of functions. In addition, I recreated the project since I had problems with app support for Android devices below Lollipop. After update and upload on Google Play, I update the app over Google Play on my separate real device (non test device) and it just keeps crashing (by opening it closes right away) without any errors on device. Google Play Console reports under "Crashes" `IllegalStateException` at

- `package.d.a (Unknown Source:73)`. However, the `d.a` package name is totally unknown for me, because I do not have that in my entire project.
- `package.MainActivity.onResume (Unknown Source:8)`. At this `8th` I have an Import which would never cause an exception.

I guess that not only me, but some another users, who already updated the app, have also the save problem. However, I just generated a signed `apk` of my app and installed it on my real device (non test device), but for this step I needed to remove the app downloaded from Google Play before manual installing. This approach worked and the app does not crashes any more and works properly without problems.

I think, for users who download the app for the first time ever, this problem does not occur for them. How can I find out the cause of the problem?

Here is my [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easyapps.cryptnote). If the app works for those who downloaded it after reading this post, please send me some short feedback using the built in `Send Feedback` in the app just to ensure the app functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use proguard you need to add the [mapping file](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281?hl=en) to your console

> If you use ProGuard to optimize and obfuscate your APK files, you can upload a ProGuard mapping file for each version of your app on the Play Console to deobfuscate your crash stack traces and help you better analyze your app's crashes.
>
> Important: Only ProGuard mapping files are supported for deobfuscation.

Comment: Hi Leo, thank you for your answer, it helped me to get closer to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any kind of testing with your app? You can try testing it on [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab), especially the Robo Tests, which try to crawl and use all app interactions.

They can help in detecting any faults or issues early on before releasing the app to the market.

You can also use [Firebase's Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/) to detect crashes and get more details on the crashes.

Comment: Hi bro, I already performed Firebase Test and the test has successfully passed. However, I tried to follow the Leo Pelozo's answer above and I will post the results asap.

Comment: Your Robo Test has passed? Great. Look into using Crashlytics for future releases after you've identified and fixed your problem. Good Luck.

Comment: So, the Leo's hint help to find out the problem. I uploaded the mapping file of my project and it helped to decode the problem. I have three problems (two in my MainActivity and one in Database class),

Comment: but non of them indicates to a real code line. For example, Google Play Console reports an IllegalStateException error in my Database class at line 85, however, this is not true since my class ends at 83th line.

Comment: The same thing with MainActivity class... I do not understand anymore what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried Firebase Crashlytics? I hear its better than Google Play crash and ANR reports. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293947/crashes-in-google-play-developer-console-vs-crashlytics-console A little more on Firebase Crashlytics: https://android.jlelse.eu/crashlytics-google-firebase-crash-reporting-for-your-android-app-132d9f8e78f2 Maybe you'll get better reports from Crashlytics or other similar tools.

Comment: Hi bro, yes, I tried, but it does not show any reports or crashes. However, I already mentioned that the app crashes in my separate non test device (a real device) and I could solve the problem by clearing the cash of app in the device settings. Now it is working.

Comment: I guess, somehow was the problem with SQLite database since it could not be used after update although I did not change anything in it while adding new functions.

Comment: Turn your comment into an answer for this question as it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In my case, I just needed to clear the cache of the app in the device settings. It helped to run the app again. However, there could be another solutions or even problems with such kind of app crash.